# Archlinux and openssh

Tags: ssh, arch-linux

I need to setup an Archlinux vps with openssh, everything is running smoothly except that I couldn't ssh in.

I noticed openssh wasn't installed so I looked on the wiki which said to do :

```
pacman -S openssh
```

I did that but it started giving me errors that it could not find openssh-5.8p2-9-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz on the mirror

```
error : failed retrieving file 'openssh-5.8p2-9-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from artfiles.org : No address record
```

I added more mirrors, but still I get the same error.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Please show us the exact error messages.

Comment: added the error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

do a complete system update

```
 # pacman -Syu
```

It looks like your system is outdated. Then try to install openssh again, however the last openssh in reporysories is openssh-5.9p1-3. Where did you placed your mirrors definitions?

Comment: where do I do this ?

Comment: run it on console as root